# How do I add an Applet inside a JFrame successfully?

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt

I have made a game in applet and I want it to add it in a `JFrame`. The reason I want to do this is because the screen that was generated by applet was resizable and I could not figure out a way to disable this property. This is a basic sample of what I have right now:

```
public class game extends Applet {

        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        public game {
         this.resize(500,500);
         f.setSize(500,500);
         f.add(this);
         f.setResizable(false);
         f.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

I added the class that inherited from applet inside the frame and it worked! However, when I run the program the applets window still opens but this time it does not have the game inside it. The game is inside the `JFrame` and works perfectly fine. I just want to get rid of the "applet frame". I am currently running the program on eclipse.

Comment: I hope you know applets are deprecated.

Comment: You don't use applets in 2018. This technology is absolutely dead. Learning about them is a waste of time and energy.

Comment: Move the "working" functionality of the "applet" into a `JPanel` then you can add it to anything you want

Comment: While it is possible to either 1) make the applet viewer non-resibale, or.. 2) launch an applet inside a frame *which is the top-level container that the applet viewer uses), I also question the benefit of making an an applet at all. Why the interest in applets, 10 years after they made even a tiny amount of sense?